# Difference between TAKE UP and TAKE ON (= to begin to do something)

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Could anyone please give me the answer of the english exercise below and help me tell apart *take up* and *take on*, which both mean *beginning to do something*? I appreciate your help with this exercise.

> You looked exhausted. I think you’ve _______ more than you can handle.
>
> A. turned on
> B. taken up
> C. turned up
> D. taken on

Comment: Thanks. I did look them up, i just couldn't know which one of them would be more suitable for the blank in the exercise and why. When looking them up in some dictionaries, i thought "take on" would be the best answer to the exercise but the key, which i got from a few websites, was take up. I got confused. But from those figures you show me above and from vm_1_r's answer, i guess the key must be "taken on"

Answer (score 2):

Well.
Take up means:

1. to start being keen on smth, to begin doing smth on regular basis.

- *I took up tennis*.
- *I wish I took up mathematics*.

And second relevant definition is

2. to consume or occupy.

- *The books on finance  take up three shelves*.
- All my time is *taken up with* looking after kids.

Whereas *take on* means

1. to begin to have or exhibit.

- In the dark, the teddy bear *took on* the appearance of a fearsome monster.

Another definition is
2. to assume responsibility for...

- *I'll **take on this project** if no one else wants to take it*.

And I guess, another appropriate meaning of *take on* is to attempt to fight or compete with.

- I don't recommend *taking on that bully*, since he is bigger than you.

Therewith, my answer to your question is

> You look exhausted. I think you've *taken on* more than you can handle.

Because it kinda means to assume responsibility for. I guess you see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you. I got it